# command is not working in shell script it is working as a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I am executing command i can able to get the result.
But I am not able to execute the command in shell script which is giving error as No such file or directory when running it from shell script.

Command :

```
cat /usr/local/apache/logs/access_??-2014-10-{11,12}.log | tail
```

Shell Script:

```
REPORT_DATE=`date --date=yesterday +%Y-%m-%d`
ACCESS_LOG_REPORT_DATE=`date --date="$REPORT_DATE" +%d/%b/%Y`

DATE_YEAR=`date --date="$REPORT_DATE" +%Y`
DATE_MONTH=`date --date="$REPORT_DATE" +%m`
DATE_DAY=`date --date="$REPORT_DATE" +%d`
DAYSTOSUBTRACT="-1 day"
DATE_DAY_SUBSTRACTED=`date --date="$REPORT_DATE$DAYSTOSUBTRACT" +%d`

WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOGS_PATH="/usr/local/apache/logs/"

WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_EXT="access_??-$DATE_YEAR-$DATE_MONTH-{$DATE_DAY_SUBSTRACTED,$DATE_DAY}.log"

WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_FILENAME=$WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOGS_PATH$WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_EXT

READFROM=`cat $WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_FILENAME | tail`
```

when I am executing shell script it is throwing error as

```
cat: /usr/local/apache/logs/access_??-2014-10-{11,12}.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try to define WEB_SERVER_ACCES_LOG_EXT without the "

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use glob pattern characters like `*` or `?` inside the quotes. Shell will only expand when they are outside quote. So you can use:

```
READFROM=$(cat access_??-"$DATE_YEAR-$DATE_MONTH-{$DATE_DAY_SUBSTRACTED,$DATE_DAY}.log" | tail)
```

Comment: Note that `cat a b | tail` is not the same as `tail a b`

Comment: I have used the glob patterns in another commands in shell scripts they are working fine. I am facing problem with this only.

Comment: Wherever you use them, just make sure `?`, `*` etc aren't quoted. Did you try my suggested one?

Comment: Yeah anubhava. I have tried it but i did got the same result.

Comment: What is the exact log file name in `/usr/local/apache/logs/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can update as follows:

```
WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_FILENAME=`eval echo $WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOGS_PATH${WEB_SERVER_ACCESS_LOG_EXT}`
```

Comment: [use of eval is discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), unless, it is impossible to get the job done otherwise OR if you really trust the input.